GPU Passthrough + MIG (vGPUs)
I have 4 GPU A100 PCIe 80GB. I'd like to use the first two GPUs for PCI Passthrough on KVM/OpenStack and the other two for vGPU (MIG).
For the first two, I'd like to use the VFIO driver, and for the other two, I'd like to use the NVIDIA driver.
Is this possible?
Details:
# lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -i "3D Controller"
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GA100 [A100 PCIe 80GB] [10de:20b5] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GA100 [A100 PCIe 80GB] [10de:1533]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
--
41:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GA100 [A100 PCIe 80GB] [10de:20b5] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GA100 [A100 PCIe 80GB] [10de:1533]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
--
81:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GA100 [A100 PCIe 80GB] [10de:20b5] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GA100 [A100 PCIe 80GB] [10de:1533]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
--
c4:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GA100 [A100 PCIe 80GB] [10de:20b5] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GA100 [A100 PCIe 80GB] [10de:1533]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

~# nvidia-smi
Mon Jul 15 10:47:39 2024
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.183.01             Driver Version: 535.183.01   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA A100 80GB PCIe          Off | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                   On |
| N/A   39C    P0              43W / 300W |      0MiB / 81920MiB |     N/A      Default |
|                                         |                      |              Enabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA A100 80GB PCIe          Off | 00000000:41:00.0 Off |                   On |
| N/A   40C    P0              47W / 300W |      0MiB / 81920MiB |     N/A      Default |
|                                         |                      |              Enabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  NVIDIA A100 80GB PCIe          Off | 00000000:81:00.0 Off |                   On |
| N/A   39C    P0              44W / 300W |     87MiB / 81920MiB |     N/A      Default |
|                                         |                      |              Enabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  NVIDIA A100 80GB PCIe          Off | 00000000:C4:00.0 Off |                   On |
| N/A   39C    P0              45W / 300W |     87MiB / 81920MiB |     N/A      Default |
|                                         |                      |              Enabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| MIG devices:                                                                          |
+------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| GPU  GI  CI  MIG |                   Memory-Usage |        Vol|      Shared           |
|      ID  ID  Dev |                     BAR1-Usage | SM     Unc| CE ENC DEC OFA JPG    |
|                  |                                |        ECC|                       |
|==================+================================+===========+=======================|
|  2    7   0   0  |              12MiB /  9728MiB  | 14      0 |  1   0    0    0    0 |
|                  |               0MiB / 16383MiB  |           |                       |
+------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|  2    8   0   1  |              12MiB /  9728MiB  | 14      0 |  1   0    0    0    0 |
|                  |               0MiB / 16383MiB  |           |                       |
+------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|  2    9   0   2  |              12MiB /  9728MiB  | 14      0 |  1   0    0    0    0 |
|                  |               0MiB / 16383MiB  |           |                       |
+------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|  2   11   0   3  |              12MiB /  9728MiB  | 14      0 |  1   0    0    0    0 |
|                  |               0MiB / 16383MiB  |           |                       |
+------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|  2   12   0   4  |              12MiB /  9728MiB  | 14      0 |  1   0    0    0    0 |
|                  |               0MiB / 16383MiB  |           |                       |
+------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|  2   13   0   5  |              12MiB /  9728MiB  | 14      0 |  1   0    0    0    0 |
|                  |               0MiB / 16383MiB  |           |                       |
+------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|  2   14   0   6  |              12MiB /  9728MiB  | 14      0 |  1   0    0    0    0 |
|                  |               0MiB / 16383MiB  |           |                       |
+------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|  3    7   0   0  |              12MiB /  9728MiB  | 14      0 |  1   0    0    0    0 |
|                  |               0MiB / 16383MiB  |           |                       |
+------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|  3    8   0   1  |              12MiB /  9728MiB  | 14      0 |  1   0    0    0    0 |
|                  |               0MiB / 16383MiB  |           |                       |
+------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|  3    9   0   2  |              12MiB /  9728MiB  | 14      0 |  1   0    0    0    0 |
|                  |               0MiB / 16383MiB  |           |                       |
+------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|  3   11   0   3  |              12MiB /  9728MiB  | 14      0 |  1   0    0    0    0 |
|                  |               0MiB / 16383MiB  |           |                       |
+------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|  3   12   0   4  |              12MiB /  9728MiB  | 14      0 |  1   0    0    0    0 |
|                  |               0MiB / 16383MiB  |           |                       |
+------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|  3   13   0   5  |              12MiB /  9728MiB  | 14      0 |  1   0    0    0    0 |
|                  |               0MiB / 16383MiB  |           |                       |
+------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|  3   14   0   6  |              12MiB /  9728MiB  | 14      0 |  1   0    0    0    0 |
|                  |               0MiB / 16383MiB  |           |                       |
+------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+-----------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


# cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"

# uname -a
Linux gpu004 6.5.0-41-generic #41~22.04.2-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jun  3 11:32:55 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-41-generic root=UUID=e8e591aa-3d0e-4e6f-aa30-43559c96fe7c ro systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0 iommu=pt intel_iommu=on default_hugepagesz=2M transparent_hugepage=never hugepages=225280 hugepagesz=2M vfio-pci.ids=10de:20b5:0000:01:00.0,10de:20b5:0000:41:00.0 vfio_iommu_type1.allow_unsafe_interrupts=1 modprobe.blacklist=nvidiafb,nouveau

Note:  I tried this vfio-pci.ids=10de:20b5 as well in the grub and in the files.
# cat /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
vfio
vfio_iommu_type1
vfio_virqfd
vfio_pci ids=10de:20b5:0000:01:00.0,10de:20b5:0000:41:00.0
vfio-pci

# cat /etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf
options vfio_pci ids=10de:20b5:0000:01:00.0,10de:20b5:0000:41:00.0

# cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf
blacklist nouveau
blacklist nvidiafb

# cat blacklist-nouveau.conf
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0

